# Differential entropy of a kernel density estimator

Tags: entropy, kernel-smoothing

I have a set of (~500k) observations that I use to fit a parametric model (univariate three-parameter lognormal). To have an idea of the goodness of fit, I want to compute the Jensen-Shannon distance to a kernel density estimator (held for the "true", or at least, a truer approximation of the sample distribution).

My kernel density estimator has the form
$$
\hat{f}_{\text{KDE}}(x) = \frac{1}{x h \sqrt{2\pi}}\sum_i w_i \exp\left(-\frac{\ln^2\left(x/x_i\right)}{2h^2}\right)
$$
(using a lognormal kernel to account for the shape of my sample distribution, with constant window width $h$, observations $x_i$ and weights $w_i$ summing to 1).

Now there is a closed-form of the entropy of the lognormal distribution. I compute the KDE entropy (and the average entropy of the two estimators) numerically. But as I have a lot of different samples on which I want to perform this computation, having a closed-form for the entropy $-\int_0^{\infty} \hat{f}_{\text{KDE}}(x)\ln\left(\hat{f}_{\text{KDE}}(x)\right)\mathrm{d}x$ as well would really speed things up. I did not manage to get one, the log of the sum seeming rather intractable to me; I'd be happy to know if a closed-form for the differential entropy of a linear combination of distributions is indeed impossible to get!

Comment: I suspect there's no closed form expression. But, it seems odd to measure goodness of fit the way you described. In particular, to consider a KDE as ground truth when it's actually another model (with it's own parameters to estimate). Why not measure goodness of fit the usual way, e.g. using the Cramer Von Mises, Kolmogorov Smirnov, or Anderson Darling statistics? These compare your model directly to the empirical distribution of the data.

Comment: @user20160 I know the KDE is not the "true truth" (emphasis on the quotation marks), but this truth doesn't exist, and it's probably closer to it than any parametric model. I think I have enough data points for it to be quite a reasonable estimation of the density; that I check visually against an histogram, as I do with the LN fit, I just need a way to quantify the discrepancy. On the other end, the size of my sample makes it very likely for e.g. a KS test to throw me off; I do know that my fit doesn't exactly represent my data, but it's a convenient way to compress it.

Comment: @user20160 I find the JS distance to be quite convenient as its range is [0, 1], making it easy to interpret. Another measure could be the EMD, computed as the integrated distance between the CDFs (which kind of extends a KS test). On the one hand, I don't need an estimated PDF to compute it, as I can use my experimental CDF; but on the other end, it's unbounded and the fact that my ECDF has as many discontinuities as I have data points make it a pain to integrate numerically (it's doable by splitting it up, but it takes time).